# Access 2007 and Terminals

Tags: ms-access, terminal, ms-access-2007

I work for a small company and they asked me to build a simple access database. They only have terminals in the office that I work in (Ottawa) while the server is in Toronto (windows server 2003). When I load Access 2007 the whole program is extremely slow compared to normal speeds of the terminal. Only when I am in any form of Design View does my Terminal speed up. My question is; is there a way to increase the "speed" of Access when I'm trying to build the database and secondly will this effect the end user once the database is built? (everyone uses terminals)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of the word terminal can mean many things here, but it does sound like you have a decent setup that should be able to work with good performance.

Also, the fact that you suggest that when in design mode, the application seems to speed up suggests the use of what is called a persistent connection may very well solve your problem.

Given that you using some type of remote desktop technology here than in fact network speeds should not really come into play and slow down the operation of this application by any noticeable amount.

First of all if there's multiple users using this application, as a general rule you should split the database into two parts, a front end part, and a so called back end part.  Because you using a terminal technology, then the front ends and back ends will remain on the server, but each individual user logging into the system could have their OWN copy of the front end.

The next thing to do is to check what call the persisting connection, and in fact access is quite sensitive to local network printers.  In your case when a user logs into this terminal system, often a local printer is "created" that is part of your local terminal but you still running Access on the server and Access will attempt to "talk" to that local network printer. So this forces additional communication between Access on the server and your default printer which is local.

I would attempt to setting a default printer that is NOT local to your WorkStation, and see if that helps.  There's also a great list of other things to check in terms of slowing down performance, and a great FAQ you want to look at is here:

http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/performancefaq.htm

In the above the persistent connection idea is also suggested.